# Select Top User over a list of Pages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing records of Users' internet history.  The table's structure contains the **User_ID**, the **Page Accessed**, and the **Date Accessed** of the page.  For Example:

```
+==========================================+ 
|User_ID  | Page_Accessed | Date_Accessed  |
+==========================================+
|Johh.Doe | Google        |    1/1/2015    |
|Johh.Doe | Google        |    1/1/2015    |
|Suzy.Lue | Google        |    7/11/2015   | 
|Suzy.Lue | Wikipedia     |    4/23/2015   |
|Babe Ruth| StackOverflow |    9/1/2015    |
+==========================================+
```

I am currently trying to use a SQL query that uses:

`RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Page Accessed] ORDER BY Count(DateAcc))`

Then I use a PIVOT() by the Various Sites. However after selecting the records `WHERE (Num = 1)` from the PIVOT() and a GROUP BY [Rank], I'm ending up with resulting query similar to:

```
+=================================================+ 
|Rank     | Google  | Wikipedia  |  StackOverflow |
+=================================================+
|   1     | John Doe|    NULL    |     NULL       |
|   1     |   NULL  |  Suzy Lue  |     NULL       |
|   1     |   NULL  |    NULL    |     Babe Ruth  | 
+=================================================+
```

Instead I need to reformat my output as:

```
+=================================================+ 
|Rank     | Google  | Wikipedia  |  StackOverflow |
+=================================================+
|   1     | John Doe| Suzy Lue   |   Babe Ruth    |
+=================================================+
```

My Current Query:

```
SELECT Rank, Google, Wikipedia, StackOverflow
    FROM(
        SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT User_ID, Page_Accessed, COUNT(Date_Accessed) AS Views, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Page_Accessed ORDER BY Count(Date_Accessed) DESC) AS Rank

        FROM   Record_Table
        GROUP BY dbo.location_key.subSite, dbo.user_info_list_parse.Name
    ORDER BY Views DESC) AS tb 

    PIVOT (
    max(tb.User_ID) FOR 
    Page_Accessed IN ( Google, Wikipedia, StackOverflow)
    ) pvt

WHERE (Num = 1)
```

Are there any creative solutions to obtain this result?

Comment: Provide your full query.

Comment: Not so creative, but .... Just add  a max() to each of the fields except rank and group by rank. `...max(google) as google, max(wikipedia) as wikipedia, max(Stackoverflow) as StackOverflow.... Group by Rank`

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `Date_Accessed` as your aggregated field parameter for the `PIVOT` - this is why your grain "off"

Comment: Good Catch @Nicarus! I must have switched those when messing around with my code earlier.  I now have the User_ID as the Aggregate for PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've already found solution but for your information and for others reading this - let me erase noise in this query. There is no need to ORDER BY, no need to apply TOP (100) PERCENT, Views column is redundant. I would simplify this query as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE InternetHistory
(
    [User_ID] varchar(20),
    [Page_Accessed] varchar(20),
    [Date_Accessed] datetime
)
INSERT InternetHistory VALUES
('Johh.Doe', 'Google', '2015-01-01'),
('Johh.Doe', 'Google', '2015-01-01'),
('Suzy.Lue', 'Google', '2015-07-11'),
('Suzy.Lue', 'Wikipedia', '2015-04-23'),
('Babe Ruth', 'StackOverflow', '2015-01-09')

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [User_ID], [Page_Accessed], RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Page_Accessed] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Ranking
    FROM InternetHistory
    GROUP BY [User_ID], [Page_Accessed]
) AS Src
PIVOT
(
    MAX([User_Id]) FOR [Page_Accessed] IN ([Google], [Wikipedia], [StackOverflow])
) AS Pvt
WHERE Ranking = 1
```

Comment: Very succinct.  Thanks for your input as well!